# How can I read bytes of file in tsql with server connection?

Tags: t-sql, byte

I use this code to read .mp3 file bytes in sql server. When I use local connection, It works correctly. But when I change connection to server(for example : **192.168.1.1** and **windows authentication mode**) and run it I get error.

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(ID INT, AudioFileName VARCHAR(50),AudioFileColumn VARBINARY(MAX))
INSERT INTO @Table1 (ID, AudioFileName, AudioFileColumn)
SELECT 1, 'Name1', BulkColumn FROM
OPENROWSET (BULK N'\\fs1\Projects\Data\DATABASE\FAQ\File1.mp3', SINGLE_BLOB)  AS x
SELECT * FROM @Table1
```

error :

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Cannot bulk load because the file
>   "\fs1\Projects\Data\DATABASE\FAQ\File1.mp3" could not be opened.
>   Operating system error code 5(failed to retrieve text for this error.
>   Reason: 15105).

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess SQL Server can't use BULK operations from non-local places. You passed a network address and it's not true. Maybe first of all you should upload your file on your server

Comment: I use BULK operations from non-local places for text files!